# Is it possible to run perl scripts from Android.mk

Tags: android, perl, makefile

I am simply wondering if it is possible to run a perl script from a make file for android! I am not familiar with how they make files work and ideally would like to add just a few lines to a make file to make this possible. If it is possible could you please show me how? And give examples!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you want to run the perl command while building a specific target, or did you want to run the perl command when make is first run?

```
#some makefile

# the following will run when the makefile is being read
# regardless of what target(s) you're building.  The output
# is stored in some_var
# Note: if the perl program has side effects (generates a file, etc), then
# this is not recommended practice.
some_var := $(shell perl someparams 1)

# the following would be run if you run "make some_target", or
# just "make" as it's the first and therefore the default target
some_target:
     @echo building $@
     perl someparams 2
```

Either way, you should likely read a primer on makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can run *any command* from `make`, `perl` is just another one.

Comment: Could you please give an example as to how this would work? Is it as simple as adding a line that states:

perl script.pl

Or is there something more that needs to be added?